# Where should backend API be called - in use case or in repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

We are doing architecture for our new android application that requires offline mode also and have a dilemma about one detail.

General recommended architecture is shown in this picture:
[image: General recommended architecture is shown in this picture:]

Now, this makes pressure on repository doing 2 things: communication with API and SQLite which can easily get very complicated + harder to test.
At the same time, we have Use Case in between ViewModel and Repository to orchestrate jobs done across multiple things: services, multiple repositories, etc...

The question is:

Should backend API be called from Repository or maybe better to do it in Use Case? And why?

Answer (score 1):

IMO neither. Generally I prefer this kind of architecture layering:

- `RemoteSource` - Communicates with your networking or bluetooth API. It essentially wraps the retrofit interfaces, and does mapping & thread switching to IO
- `LocalSource` - Communicates with your DB api (Room, SqlDelight). Also mapping & thread switching
- `Repository` - Handles the logistics, whether something should be fetched, cached, etc...
- `UseCase` - Combines multiple type of entity operations between repositories

So **TL;DR**: you can create a `RemoteSource` abstraction over your `Retrofit` interfaces

Comment: where do you call your `Remote Source` from? from use case or from repository?

Comment: Depends, if I don't have neither a `MemorySource` nor a `LocalSource`, then the repo layer IMO is overhead. But otherwise I call it from the repository. Something like this:

`class Repository { fun get() = remoteSource.get().also { localSource.cache(it) } }`

Comment: ok, then back to the original question: why from repository and not from use case? /not saying any is right or wrong, i’d just like to hear reasons.

Comment: Well I believe a `UseCase`'s responsibility is to combine different type of entities, while Repository combines the same type of entity coming from different sources.

For ex you may have a `GetFeedItemsUseCase()`, which combines multiple type of items like `Image`, `News`,  etc...